# React Redux: Component not updated after connecting to redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

The question may seem redundant, but my component does not seem to update after mapStateToProps is called. Below is a piece of code I wrote inside my Home Component ( ofc outside the class declaration).

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { tickets } = state;
  console.tron.log(tickets)
  if(!tickets.isLoading) {
    return {
      loading: false,
      ticketsModel: tickets.chunkedData
    }
  }
  return {
    loading: true
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Everything works fine, but the changes to props is not triggering update in my component.

PS: I checked whether any state mutations takes place, but no it din't. I recreated a new state like

```
case RECEIVE_TICKETS :
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isLoading: false,
        chunkedData: action.data.extractChunkedData(),
        completeData: action.data.getCompleteData(),
      });
```

[image: A picture demonstrating the last Action Dispatch]

**EDIT: The Problem has been sorted. Silly me was checking for updates inside componentWillMount instead of componentWillReceiveProps**

Comment: maybe something is not right in your Home component? can you post that? are you saying that if you put a console log in `render` it's not firing after a state change?

Comment: can you share your component code?

Comment: @azium exactly. I haven't completed my Component code yet. But when the state changes, componentWillUpdate should be called right. That's where the problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your mapStateToProps more concisely like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { isLoading, chunkedData } = state.tickets;
  return {
    loading: isLoading,
    ticketsModel: chunkedData
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

After looking at your `mapStateToProps` function, and the Redux logger, your problem is most likely in the component itself. If you were to render `this.props.loading` in your component, you should see `true` and then `false`.

Also, I see that you do not have an initial state on your chunkedData array. When you set the initial state of the `tickets` object, you should set that to an empty array.

So first few lines of your reducer should look like this:

```
const tickets = (
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    chunkedData: [],
    // Need more info to know what would go in this object
    completeData: {} 
  },
  action
) => {
```

See if you can see the props change in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. You should be able to `console.log()` the nextProps, that will change whenever the props change.

Read more about lifecycle methods here: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/